# I can't install a .sh file

Tags: .sh

I can't install a .sh file. When I double click the file then it is open with archive manager not get any run or run in terminal option.

I also checked the permission on allow executing file as program

Comment: `*.sh` files are shell scripts, they should be human readable. Please post the output of `cat yourfile.sh`.

Comment: Open terminal, run as command line: `./path_to_shfile/your_file.sh`

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: What is the .sh script you're trying execute & where is the exact location of the file?? at lease can advise you how to execute from the terminal

Comment: they are in the same folder in the desktop

Answer (score 3):

To run .sh file, using a terminal is the best way.

Assuming your file is in `/home/user/downloads` directory;

To open a terminal press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> together. Once the terminal is opened, type `pwd` to locate which directory currently you're in. `pwd` will display an output like below

```
/root/folder/
```

If your **.sh** file is in user's downloads directory as I mentioned above, then use `cd` command to navigate to the downloads folder. see below;

```
cd /home/user/downloads
```

once entered, again check whether you're in that directory by using `pwd` command. If you're in that directory then simply type `ls` command to list down the files. Once you see your **.sh** file, simply type below command to execute the file.

```
sudo sh shell_file.sh
```

terminal will ask you to type the root (admin) password which will not be visible while you type. simply type the password & enter. That's it, the execution will process.

This is just an assumption; assuming your file located in a directory. I hope this very basic and simplified process which will make you more clear.

Hope it helps! :)

**EDIT:** I've edited the document by adding **sh** command at the last step.

Comment: when i using this method at the last step means when i type sudo myfile.sh and press enter it says command not found

Comment: my bad.. I'm so sorry that I missed `sh` command at the last step.. please try it again let us know. :)

Comment: Now it says- install.sh(my filename):31:install.sh:function:not found ubuntu install.sh:46: install.sh syntax error: "}" unexpected

Comment: Hmm pretty strange.. is that `.sh` file created by you or downloaded from any source to achieve something?? Can you try; `sudo bash ./file_name.sh` instead :)

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works. So the question will not be queued anymore. :)

Answer (score -1):

first give full permission to that .sh file

```
sudo chmod 755 YOUR_FILENAME
```

second run .sh file by following command inside ur CLI

```
sudo ./YOUR_FILENAME
```

**YOUR_FILENAME is full path of your file, where it is situated.

Comment: It *is* correct what you're saying, but compared to the original question, lacking in substance.

Comment: `chmod 777` is not recommended since it gives write permissions to 'others' also. `chmod 755` is the way to go...

Comment: fair enough @rohith-madhavan